# Changing border-radius when element is in view - how can I change percentage to pixels

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have found some code which will change the border radius of my div on scroll. It works but it's a percentage, not a pixel.

```
var hHeight = $("html").height(),
    radius  = 10;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      percentage   = 0 + ((1*scrollTop)/hHeight) * 2;
  $(".video_content").css("border-radius", percentage + "%");
});
```

When this div is in view, I want the border-radius to go from 0px to 10px. I've tweaked it a ton, but no success yet.

Here's the codepen I started with: https://codepen.io/yy/pen/ByrMZR

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using window.scroll() will negatively impact the performance of your application because it checks for smallest of the movements. What you can do instead is use the Intersection Observer API, like so:

```
const changeRadiusCallBk = (entries, observer) => {
  const [entry] = entries; //destructuring 0th element into entry variable
  if (entry.isIntersecting)
    document.querySelector('.video_content').classList.add('chg-border-radius');
  else document.querySelector('.video_content').classList.remove('chg-border-radius');
  //If you want to only have the effect once, uncomment below line and comment the above else
  //observer.unobserve(document.querySelector('.video_content'));
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(changeRadiusCallBk, {
  root: null,
  //experiment with treshold to see how much of your dom element should be in view before effect kicks in.
  //i.e should it be 50% in view? then use 0.5.
  threshold: 0.5,
  //experiment with the rootMargin positive and negative values or generate it
  //dynamically to see when you want your effect to kick in
  rootMargin: '-10px',
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.video_content'));
```

**EDIT:**
**CSS for smoother Border Radius Transition:**

```
.chg-border-radius{
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: border-radius 0.6s linear; //play around with this
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any way to make the rounding less harsh, e.g. slow down the speed that the .video_content div goes from 0px to 10px border radius?

Comment: Yes, you can make the transition smooth using the 'transition' CSS property, I have modified my answer to include that as well, please take a look. I would recommend that, instead of manipulating the element's style.borderRadius property directly, just add the above mentioned css in a css class selector and dynamically add and remove that class from your element using document.querySelector('.video_content').classList.add/remove functions like I have now changed above.

Answer (score 0):

in your VERY specific case ( 0 to 10 ) you can use that percentage and divide it by 10.

And a little bit of tweaking so you go backwards : from 0 to 10 not 100 to 0 like it does now

```js
var hHeight = $("html").height(),
    radius  = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      percent   = 0 + ((100*scrollTop)/hHeight) * 2;
  $(".round").css("border-radius", percent/10 + "px");
});
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  background: #333;
}
.round {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: -50%;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="round"></div>
```